# Updating column based on other column values in the same table

Tags: sql

I have two columns. 'A' is consisted of enum values (0,1,2) other 'B' is nullable Boolean. I need to update 'B' based on A.

```
Case 0 -> null
Case 1 - false
Case 2 - true
```

What is the correct way to do that?

Comment: And what's expected to happen if someone later updates a 1 to a 2?

Comment: I am dropping A after this

Comment: SQL Server has no `boolean` data type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using a CASE expression:

```
update the_table
   set b = case a 
              when 0 then null 
              when 1 then false
              when 2 then true
           end;
```

Answer (score 1):

In SQL we can update the column value based on condition using CASE statement.

```
UPDATE TableName SET B = CASE 
  WHEN A= 0 THEN NULL
  WHEN A= 1 THEN False(0)
  WHEN A =  2 THEN True(1)
   END
```